# Bathroom Mirror Sensor doesn't have enough free space to function properly

Tags: bathroom, ceiling, gap, motion-sensor, mirror

I have the bathroom mirror below hanging from the ceiling. Unfortunately the sensor needs at least 15cm free space to function properly. Currently it only has about 10cm. I cannot replace the mirror since the tile has been cut to mount it on the ceiling. So looking for alternatives to make the sensor work. The sensor controls the demister and light.

How easy would it be to replace the sensor with a manual switch? Alternatively is there a way to extend the sensor so that I can move it to the side of the mirror instead of being at the bottom?

Appreciate any guidance

https://www.victorianplumbing.co.uk/arezzo-matt-black-600mm-hanging-led-illuminated-bathroom-mirror-with-infrared-sensor-and-anti-fog

[image]

Comment: A sensor is about the same as an automatic switch.  Changing to a manual switch might be easy or hard, depending on the wiring, how easy it is to get at the wiring to bypass the sensor.  Having those heaters on a manual switch might be a bad idea.  Forget to turn off and leave the heaters on to make fire.

Comment: I don't see where the instruction manual for the mirror available on the linked website says anything about a mounting clearance of 15cm needed. May have missed it. Where do you see a specified mounting clearance?

Comment: Also, modifying the mirror may break whatever safety listing the manufacturer received, and in case of fire that @crip659 surmised, the insurance company may not pay the claim.

Comment: The 15cm clearance is on a sticker at the bottom of the mirror. And it doesn't work properly right now where the clearance is less than 10cm. Re warranty, i am ok with losing it since without the sensor, i cannot even use the lights and the demister. so just need a solution to make it work

Comment: In which direction does it need 15 cm (~6" for us left-pondians) of clearance and how is it that you can't get that much clearance? It seems that it's height adjustable, so if it's distance below, raise it 5cm... Maybe a pic of your actual installation showing the issue would be helpful.

Comment: It needs 15cm at the bottom. I have attached a pic now to help. The height is already adjusted to be as high as possible but as you can see from the pic, the clearance at the bottom is < 10cm.

Comment: aren't the bars that it suspends from just threaded?  can't you just cut them and re-thread them for the mirror to go higher?

Comment: remove the protective film and test again

Comment: @FreshCodemonger - that is currently the most likely solution except the wire connection for the demister/light come through the rod so cutting them might also cut the wire accidentally

Comment: @jsotola - Not sure I follow.

Comment: @SamVenk the picture shows protective film covering the mirror ... it may be interfering with the sensor

Comment: Were the support bars connected to both the escutcheon and the mirror in the box, or did you assemble it? If you assembled it, just disassemble, cut the bars, rethread, reassemble.